# errSecItemNotFound after updating the application

Tags: ios, keychain

We are preparing for a release and during upgrade tests I came around to a blocking problem. We are saving some stuff to the keychain, and after doing the app update, the app keeps throwing errSecItemNotFound after attempting SecItemCopyMatching.

```
CFTypeRef   identity_ref     = NULL;
const void *keys[] =   { kSecClass, kSecReturnRef,  kSecValuePersistentRef };
const void *values[] = { kSecClassIdentity, kCFBooleanTrue, persistent_ref };
CFDictionaryRef dict = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, keys, values,
                                          3, NULL, NULL);

OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching(dict, &identity_ref);

if (DEBUG) NSLog(@"%s --> status: %d", __func__, (int)status);
```

Now, I've never personally used Keychain. This code is written by someone that isn't working anymore. I will start reading up on keychain to understand how it works, but I decided to post a question here in the meantime in the hope that I will receive an answer before I figure it out by myself (the release is waiting :D).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem the two versions pointed to two different keychain-sharing-groups. Mofos...